# Why do you have to use an asterisk for pointers but not struct pointers?

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I think I am missing a part of technical background. But I don't get, why I have to use an * to access the value of a simple pointer, but not for accessing values of a struct.

For example with a simple value:

```
func main() {
    i := 42
    p := &i
    *p = 21         // <<< I have to use an asterisk to access the value
    // ...
}
```

And a example with a struct:

```
type Vertex struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{1, 2}
    p := &v
    p.X = 1e9       // <<< I do not have to use an asterisk
    // ...
}
```

(yes, the samples are from the official go lang tour here: https://go-tour-de.appspot.com/moretypes/4)

Just from my thoughts I would expect something like this

```
    *p.X = 1e9
```

or (yeah, this would be somewhat strange)

```
    p.*X = 1e9
```

So, why don't I have to use an asterisk to access struct pointer?

Comment: Syntactic sugar to make a programmer's life easier.

Comment: I think you're talking about struct fields, not structs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official Golang tour where you found that example [[here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/)] explicitly says:

> To access the field `X` of a struct when we have the struct pointer `p` we could write `(*p).X`. However, that notation is cumbersome, so the language permits us instead to write just `p.X`, without the explicit dereference.

Comment: Great! I used the German version of the tour to find an answer and there this little but important detail is missing (https://go-tour-de.appspot.com/moretypes/4). Note to myself, always use the english original documentation. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know there were versions in other languages, and didn't expect there to be different content. Good to know, thanks.